# Issue with linked list method without parameter

Tags: java, methods, parameters, iterator

This method builds a new LinkedList with the odd numbered elements from a given LinkedList.
For instance, if the given LinkedList has size 100, starting at location 0 (the head), 
and going 1,2,3,..., 99 (the tail), the OddList returns a new LinkedList with elements from
 1,3,5,7, .. 99

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.util.*;

public class ExtLinkedList<E> extends LinkedList<E> 
{
    public ExtLinkedList<E> oddItemsList ( ) 
    {
        ExtLinkedList<E> extendedll = new ExtLinkedList<E>();  //linked list im returning
        ListIterator itr = extendedll.listIterator(); //allows me to manipulate list 
        return extendedll; 
    }
}
```

What I am confused on is how do I modify a "given" linked list without being given a linked list in the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that this method is a method of a class `ExtLinkedList`.  When `l` is a list with elements `(1 2 3 4)`, the intention is that `l.oddItemsList()` returns a list with elements `(1 3)`.

The description of the method is a bit misleading, but if the method were supposed to take a list as an argument, it wouldn't need to access of the instance data in an instance of the class, and could be declared `static`.  It's not, though, so it's reasonable to infer that “the given list” means “the instance whose method is being called.”